# Redirect to Visualforce page after click in other Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, redirect

I'm creating a parent and multiple child records on single click from vfpage.
Now I want to show that created parent and child records on another page. How can I do that?Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Solution can be very easy. Just create a visualforce page, that query in controller newly created record and all children, and shows that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same controller for the other page. and in the first page while setting the redirect to go to the second page , set redirect to false.

More explanation in the link below 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm